# Vertx: How to verify auth before handle body request?

Tags: vert.x, kotlin-coroutines

How to verify auth before handle body request?

I'm using vertx:

```
vertxVersion = '3.8.3'
implementation "io.vertx:vertx-core:$rootProject.vertxVersion"
implementation "io.vertx:vertx-web:$rootProject.vertxVersion"
implementation "io.vertx:vertx-lang-kotlin:$rootProject.vertxVersion"
implementation "io.vertx:vertx-lang-kotlin-coroutines:$rootProject.vertxVersion"
implementation "io.vertx:vertx-mongo-client:$rootProject.vertxVersion"
implementation "io.vertx:vertx-auth-mongo:$rootProject.vertxVersion"
implementation "io.vertx:vertx-auth-jwt:$rootProject.vertxVersion"
```

I want to verify auth before handle body request. But I got error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request has already been read`

Reproduce by use delay on suspend function:

```
router.handler { context ->
            launch {
                context.request().setExpectMultipart(true)
                delay(100) //This line is sample for a verify auth process
                context.next()
            }
        }
        .handler {context ->
            println("2")
            context.request()
                .handler {
                    b -> println("buff ${b.length()}")
                }
                .endHandler {
                    println("end handle")
                    context.success("ok")
                }
        }.baseHandle(
            fn
        ).failureHandler {
            println("fail: ${it.failure()}")
            it.error()
        }
```

When run `delay(100)` (this's sample for a verify process), I got the error above. If I comment `delay(100)`, It's will be working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I did solve it.

My router is working with the flows:

```
router.post("/api/upload/file")
      .baseHandle { checkAuthorization(it) }
      .handleFileUpload { updateFileOnItem(it) }
```

And Following step:

```
fun checkAuthorization(context: RoutingContext) {
    val request = context.request()
    val tkCookie = request.getCookie("user")
    ...do something to verify user permission
    request.pause()
    context.next()
    context.request().resume()
}
```

Next:

```
fun updateFileOnItem(context: RoutingContext) {
    val file = context.fileUploads()
    ...do something
}
```

It's working with me. Hope it can be help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because by the time you auhenticated the request, the content has kept arriving and has been dropped.

You need to invoke `context.request().pause()` in you first handler and then `context.request().resume()` when you're ready.

In most cases though it's easier to let the [`BodyHandler`](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/kotlin/#_request_body_handling) manage payload for you.

Comment: Thanks @tsegismont. I want to verify auth before handle body request. I will try to use pause and resume for to do it.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I am having the same problem. But it doesn't seem to work for me to pause then resume. I am still seeing the problem.

Comment: @NavidMitchell It's still error with me :((. Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: @PhanSinh no I did not.  Looks like something that will need to be a feature request for vertx.

Comment: @NavidMitchell Hi guy, I did solve it. Let's to see my answer. Hope it can be help you.

Comment: Thank you @PhanSinh I will try out your example.